# External Display "static" on MacBook Pro 15″ 2014

Tags: macos, display

My MacBook Pro (15", 2014, OS X Mavericks 10.9.4) and my 24" 1920x1200 monitor are not working together.

I connect the two with from the Mini DisplayPort on the Mac to DVI on the monitor. The monitor only shows a "static" effect like when an old tv cannot pick up a signal and my Mac's screen flickers ~30 seconds.

When I turn the monitor off then on, when my Mac is still connected, the monitor goes blank and the MacBook screen begins to flicker every ~3 seconds.

Does anyone know what is going on here? I ordered a DisplayPort to HDMI cable just hoping that the cable I used was faulty.

Comment: It does sound like cable, but tell us what monitor is displayed in your displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was completely the cable. I used a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable and it works perfectly.